# Exporting Yahoo emails to Outlook 2016 won't copy folders, even with IMAP

Tags: email, imap, microsoft-outlook-2016, yahoo-messenger

### UPDATE: I'd still like to do this, but with Outlook 2016.

I am trying to copy my Yahoo emails into Outlook 2010. However, when I select to **send/receive all folders**, only the Inbox will copy to Outlook. All of my other personal folders do not copy. Of course this didn't work using POP3, but I even tried using **IMAP** and it *still* won't copy my named folders from Yahoo to Outlook.

I used the following steps from [Yahoo](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4075.html):

> **IMAP server settings for Yahoo Mail**
>
> IMAP is the best way to connect your Yahoo Mail account to a desktop mail client or mobile
> app. It allows 2-way syncing, which means everything you do remotely
> is reflected in your Yahoo Mail account no matter where or how you
> access it. Here are the settings you'll need to configure your mail
> client or app.
>
> **Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server**
>
> - Server - imap.mail.yahoo.com
> - Port - 993
> - Requires SSL - Yes
>
> **Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server**
>
> - Server - smtp.mail.yahoo.com
> - Port - 465 or 587
> - Requires SSL - Yes
>   Requires authentication - Yes
>
> **Your login info**
>
> - Email address - Your full email address (name@domain.com)
> - Password - Your account's password
> - Requires authentication - Yes
>
> If you need specific instructions for your mail client or app, reach out to its manufacturer.

**Any idea how to rectify this problem??**

Comment: This is the best help Yahoo provides: https://en-global.help.yahoo.com/kb/new-mail-for-desktop/sln28681.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your view settings for your inbox. I've seen some folders and mail go hidden if you don't have IMAP view selected. Click the View Tab, change view, select IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your yahoo mail to old classic view and then update yahoo account settings in outlook would fetch/sync all folders from yahoo into outlook. I've left root folder path is not configured.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only way to transfer your folders is to do it via the inbox,
copying manually for each subfolder:

```
Yahoo subfolder ➜ Yahoo inbox ➜ Outlook inbox ➜ Outlook subfolder
```

This process is painful and slow, but only needs to be done once.

There exist commercial products that can do a full Yahoo backup
in multiple formats which might help in the migration,
some of which are:

- [Advik Yahoo Backup Tool](https://www.adviksoft.com/yahoo/backup.html)
- [Kernel IMAP Backup](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/imap-backup/).